# Difficulty with a flat surface that creates shadows

Tags: faces, shadows

My question may seem simple, I'm new to Blender. I am using version 3.1.2. On a flat surface on which I apply the BoolTool tool to create an opening, my surface behaves strangely. I get ghost shadows on the edges created by the tool. How to avoid this behavior?

Thank you!

[image: Capture]

Comment: it looks like you've shaded smooth, so maybe go into Oblect Data > Normals and enable the Auto Smooth option

Comment: Also, the bool tool is notorious for creating poor topology that does not shade well in blender - for example, your plane is now a set of several n-gon's (faces with more than 4 vertices). Blender cannot "poke holes" in the center of planes, so the "crease lines" (two in the top corners, one across the bottom) are where blender was forced to create an edge through the plane in order to accommodate the "cut. Blender shades best with quad based topology (especially curved surfaces and smooth shading), so to properly solve the issue, you will have to re-topologize (get rid of the n-gon's).

Comment: Thank you I've try with a cube and its working well, Very much Thank you!